# Qiskit's PauliTrotterEvolution yields weird gates

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, pauli-gates

I am trying to work with Qiskit's PauliTrotterEvolution() module, but the resulting circuits contain weird gates that I know nothing about.

Here is a simple example: I want to implement the fermionic creation operator on one of two qubits

```
from qiskit_nature.mappers.second_quantization import BravyiKitaevMapper
from qiskit_nature.operators.second_quantization import FermionicOp 
from qiskit.opflow.evolutions import PauliTrotterEvolution

fermi_op = FermionicOp("+I", display_format="dense")
```

The fermionic operator is mapped to a sum of Pauli gates using the Bravyi-Kitaev mapper:

```
mapper = BravyiKitaevMapper()
bosonic_op = mapper.map(fermi_op)
```

Now we apply the PauliTrotterEvolution to the exponential of the bosonic operator:

```
pauli_trotter = PauliTrotterEvolution("trotter", reps=1)

conv = pauli_trotter.convert(bosonic_op.exp_i())

circ = conv.to_circuit()

circ.draw("latex")
```

[image]

I have no clue what these "circuit" gates are. Has anyone seen something similar before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "circuit" gates are empty, if you transpile the circuit to a basis gate set they will disappear:

```
from qiskit import transpile

circ = # your circuit
transpiled = transpile(circ, basis_gates=["h", "s", "sdg", "rz", "cx"])
print(transpiled.draw())
```

As the answer of @viwosh points out, that behavior is also fixed in the newer versions of Qiskit.

Answer (score 2):

When I do this in a recent version (0.19.0.dev0+6e0926f) I get
[image]

For your version perhaps try "circ.decompose().draw('latex')" to see how "circuit-24" is defined.